# Function `run_swmm` in R package "swmmr" fails to create ".rpt" and ".out" files?

Tags: r, temporary-files, calibration

I am running a SWMM calibration example included in the R package "swmmr" (https://cran.r-hub.io/web/packages/swmmr/vignettes/How_to_autocalibrate_a_SWMM_model_with_swmmr.html). When I try to run the function `run_swmm`, the "rpt" and "out" files are not created.

Below are my steps and I wonder how to fix the error? Thank you.

1. Install SWMM from https://www.epa.gov/water-research/storm-water-management-model-swmm
2. SWMM calibration in R using "swmmr"

   ```
    remotes::install_github("dleutnant/swmmr")
    install.packages("DEoptim")
    library(swmmr)
    library(DEoptim)

    inp_file <- system.file("extdata", "Example1.inp", package = "swmmr", mustWork = TRUE)
    tmp_rpt_file <- tempfile(tmpdir = "D:/SWMM_example", fileext = ".rpt")
    tmp_out_file <- tempfile(tmpdir = "D:/SWMM_example", fileext = ".out")

    swmm_files <- run_swmm(inp = inp_file, rpt = tmp_rpt_file, 
                           out = tmp_out_file, 
                           exec = "D:/SWMM/EPA SWMM 5.2.3 (64-bit)/epaswmm5.exe")
   ```

When running the code, SWMM will run automatically, and I usually close it after 10-15 seconds so that it can finish running the example. It is expected that the ".rpt" and ".out" files will be created under "D:/SWMM_example".

However, some warnings occur as below. It seems that `run_swmm` fails to create the ".rpt" and ".out" files. I am not sure how to solve the issue.

[image]

Thanks to @Johannes Titz, I need to find the path to the command line SWMM `swmm5.exe` instead of the GUI SWMM `epaswmm5.exe`. I install the 64-bit SWMM and then use the tool `Everything` to search for "swmm5.exe", however, I could not find `swmm5.exe` on my laptop. I can only find `epaswmm5.exe`. I wonder how I should find `swmm5.exe`? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling the command line interface of swmm but the GUI. I think you need to change the executable to "swmm5.exe". Reading the doc you will see that the default is also swmm5.exe and not epaswmm5.exe:

> exec
>
> Name and path to swmm5 executable. If not manually set, the following
> paths are looked up when package gets loaded: windows: "C:/Program
> Files (x86)/EPA SWMM 5.X.XXX/swmm5.exe" not windows:
> "/usr/local/bin/swmm5" , "/usr/bin/swmm5"

Could you give this a try and report back? At least for me, this runs totally fine with swmm5.exe

Edit: The R-package was released in 2018 so I installed the swmm-version of that time, which was 5.1.013. On the newest version the naming seems to have changed to **runswmm.exe**. Can you try this?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, but I could not find "swmm5.exe" on my laptop. I installed the 64-bit SWMM, and I used "Everything" to search for "swmm5.exe". However,  I can only find "epaswmm5.exe" on my laptop. Can I ask how you find "swmm5.exe"? I have updated my question to provide more details for your reference. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, you need to use runswmm.exe. On earlier versions the command line interface was called swmm5.exe, now it is runswmm.exe -- I edited my answer.

Comment: Amazing! `runswmm.exe` works in this case. However, another error occurred when running the example. I posted another question at `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76871433/r-package-swmmr-error-error-in-file-existsexec-invalid-file-argument`, could you please take a look? Thank you.