# R package "swmmr" error: Error in file.exists(exec) : invalid 'file' argument

Tags: r, optimization

I am running a SWMM calibration example included in the R package "swmmr" (https://cran.r-hub.io/web/packages/swmmr/vignettes/How_to_autocalibrate_a_SWMM_model_with_swmmr.html).

When I try to run the example, an error occurred: `Error in file.exists(exec): invalid 'file' argument`. I wonder how I should address this issue? Thank you.

1. Install SWMM from https://www.epa.gov/water-research/storm-water-management-model-swmm
2. SWMM calibration in R using "swmmr"

   ```
   remotes::install_github("dleutnant/swmmr")
   install.packages("DEoptim")
   library(swmmr)
   library(DEoptim)

   inp_file <- system.file("extdata", "Example1.inp", package = "swmmr", mustWork = TRUE)
   tmp_rpt_file <- tempfile(tmpdir = "D:/SWMM_example", fileext = ".rpt")
   tmp_out_file <- tempfile(tmpdir = "D:/SWMM_example", fileext = ".out")

   # initiate the simulation
   swmm_files <- run_swmm(inp = inp_file, rpt = tmp_rpt_file, 
                          out = tmp_out_file, 
                          exec = "C:/Program Files/EPA SWMM 5.2.4 (64-bit)/runswmm.exe")

   obs <- read_out(file = swmm_files$out, iType = 1, object_name = "18", 
                vIndex = 4)[["18"]]$total_inflow

   # read model structure
   inp <- read_inp(swmm_files$inp) 

   # show the original parameter values
   inp$subcatchments[inp$subcatchments$Area > 10, ]

   nse <- function(x) {
          1 - sum((x[, 1] - x[, 2]) ^ 2) / sum((x[, 1] - mean(x[, 1])) ^ 2)
          }

   obj_fun <- function(x, inp, obs) {

   # set new parameters and update inp object
     inp$subcatchments <- transform(
     inp$subcatchments,
     Perc_Imperv = ifelse(Area > 10, x, Perc_Imperv)
      )

   # write new inp file to disk
     tmp_inp <- tempfile()
     write_inp(inp, tmp_inp)

   # run swmm with new parameter set
     swmm_files <- suppressMessages(run_swmm(tmp_inp, stdout = NULL))

   # remove files when function exits to avoid heavy disk usage
     on.exit(file.remove(unlist(swmm_files)))

   # read sim result
     sim <- read_out(
            file = swmm_files$out, # path to out file
            iType = 1, # type: node
            object_name = "18", # name of node
            vIndex = 4 # parameter at node: total inflow
            )[["18"]]$total_inflow # directly access to xts object

   # calculate goodness-of-fit
   # note: multiply by minus one to have a real min problem (nse: +1 to -Inf)
      nse(merge(obs, sim)) * -1
      }

     set.seed(84) # to get reproducible results

     calibration_res <- DEoptim(
                               fn = obj_fun, 
                               lower = c(0, 0), 
                               upper = c(100, 100),
                               control = list(
                                         itermax = 50, # maximum iterations
                                         trace = 10, # print progress every 10th iteration
                                         packages = c("swmmr"), # export packages to optimization environment
                                         parVar = c("nse"), # export function to optimization environment
                                         parallelType = 0 # set to 1 to use all available cores
                                         ),
                                inp = inp, # 'inp' object
                                obs = obs # xts object containing observation data
                                )
   ```

When I run `calibration_res`, an error occurs: `Error in file.exists(exec) : invalid 'file' argument`. I wonder how I can fix this error? Thanks.

[image]

The path of the SWMM exec is available blow:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: Could you try to add the exec parameter to your second call of run_swmm:

```
# change this
swmm_files <- suppressMessages(run_swmm(tmp_inp, stdout = NULL))
# to:
swmm_files <- suppressMessages(
  run_swmm(tmp_inp, stdout = NULL, 
           exec = "C:/Program Files/EPA SWMM 5.2.4 (64-bit)/runswmm.exe")
)
```

**Original answer:**
Are you sure the error comes from `calibration_res`? It runs fine for me. Can you check the path of your exec again? In the last example, in the end, you probably used:

`exec = "D:/Program Files/EPA SWMM 5.2.3 (64-bit)/runswmm.exe")`

Now, it is under `C:/` and the version changed to `5.2.4`. Is this correct?

Please check if the path really exists and report back.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just checked and the path exists. I have updated the question for your reference. Thanks.

Comment: I updated my answer; you might need to set the exec path in the second call of run_swmm too.

Comment: It finally works! You are a lifesaver, thank you very much!!!